# Is there a way to constraint the together value in Serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `EmailCreateSerializer`, I can let creator pass `receive_group` id or `receive_user` id to send an email to them:

```
class EmailCreateSerializer(Serializer):
    receive_group = serializers.IntegerField(allow_null=True)
    receive_user = serializers.IntegerField(allow_null=True)
```

Either pass the receive_group (send to a group), or receive_user (send to a single user).

But I want to have a constraint, that both of them (`receive_group`, `receive_user`) cannot be null.
Is there a way to do this in Serializer class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override Serializer's `validate()` method to check this:

```
class EmailCreateSerializer(Serializer):
    receive_group = serializers.IntegerField(allow_null=True)
    receive_user = serializers.IntegerField(allow_null=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['receive_group'] is None and data['receive_user'] is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Group or User cannot be empty, pass information for at least one of those.")
        return data
```

Documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation